Column does not exist error in Quiver Dashboard with filters on Transform Table with Left Joins
I’m currently working on a project in Palantir Foundry where I’m creating a Quiver dashboard. The dashboard uses a Transform Table to join data from multiple source transform tables. I’m using a left join mechanism to build an output table. This output table contains a set of columns from the initial transform table (A) and adds one column each from two other joined transform tables (B and C).
Everything works fine until I apply a filter on the dashboard to the resulting table. When the remaining records do not have a matching record in at least one of the two joined tables (B or C), I get an error. The error message states that the column from the joined table do not exist.
Error message is: "Column with property id "" does not exist." I then get a list of all the properties that are available.
Here’s the process I’m following:

Create a Transform Table with my initial data.
Perform a left join with two other Transform Tables, adding one column from each to my initial Transform Table.
Display the resulting table in a Quiver dashboard.
Apply a filter on the dashboard.
The error occurs at step 4 when there are no matching records in the joined tables for the remaining records after the filter is applied.

What I'm expecting is for the columns with properties derived from joined records, display null (or zero) if no matching record exists.
I’m looking for a way to handle this scenario where a filter might result in non-matching records in the joined tables. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!
